# Saving results with headers in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, ssms, export-to-excel

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

I wish to save the results of a query to an excel file.

I choose "save as" and then save to CSV file which I can open in excel. All good except I am missing column headers, any ideas how I get them exported?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

**Tools** > **Options** > **Query Results** > **SQL Server** > **Results to Text (or Grid if you want)** > **Include columns headers in the result set**

You *might* have to close and reopen SSMS after changing this option.

**Note**: On the SQL Editor Toolbar, you can click **Results to file** (Refer screenshot)  without having to restart SSMS.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> if you like keyboard shortcuts during development.

Comment: +1, Tested this and it works:  Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid, then check 'Include column headers when copying or saving the results'.

Comment: This works for SSMS 2012 - you **do need to restart SSMS** for the settings to take effect.

Comment: To confirm, you definitely need to close and reopen SSMS for this option to be applied.

Comment: Like Christopher said, you DO need to restart SSMS for the changes to work.

Comment: For SSMS 2016 you also still need to restart it for these changes to take affect.

Comment: Need to expand the node of "SQL Server" to find the node of Results to Gird. (I missed this at the beginning so trying to help here. )

Comment: AFTER APPLIED the setting Need to RESTART the SQL SMSS and run again the query, and save the result to .CSV

Comment: I have not restarted the whole SSMS (had a lot of unsaved queries in other windows), but only started a new query window, and it worked as expected. The Version of SSMS is 18.4 (SSMS component version 15.0.18206.0)

Comment: To confirm, you need to open a new query window for the changes to take effect, but you do not need to restart SSMS.

Comment: This is the correct answer but if you have a set of results that you really don't want to discard then RBT's answer allows you to avoid a restart for existing windows

Answer (score 37):

Try the Export Wizard. In this example I select a whole table, but you can just as easily specify a query:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(you can also specify a query here)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. But this is for tables. My question was for a query.

Comment: You can also specify a query in the fourth step - "Specify Table Copy or Query".

Comment: I tried all of the other approaches, and this is the only one that worked for my mixed datatypes.

Comment: While this works it is very painful and time consuming. SQL Server and Excel are both MS products, it is amazing that there is not a simple export button in the year 2013!

Comment: This method would be the very definition of crossing the river to pick up water.

Answer (score 37):

Another possibility is to use the clipboard to copy and paste the results directly into Excel. Just be careful with General type Excel columns, as they can sometimes have unpredictable results, depending on your data. `CTL-A` anywhere in the result grid, and then right-click:

[image]

If you have trouble with Excel's General format doing undesired conversions, select the blank columns in Excel before you paste and change the format to "text".

Comment: This is great, except for Excel formatting. Numbers with leading zeroes (e.g. mobile numbers) drop the zeroes in Excel. There are other formatting problems lying in wait as well, use at your own peril. Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: One trick I've learned for the Excel formatting is to paste it, then (with the pasted area still highlighted) change the format of the selected area to Text.  Then paste again on top.  Now the leading zeros etc. should be preserved.

Answer (score 15):

The setting change which has been advised in [Diego's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677148/465053) is perfect if we want to enable this option *permanently* in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Here *permanently* means the new setting will get applied automatically to *all* future query sessions in SSMS. This is usually *not* the case. Many a times we want to enable this option *temporarily* and then revert back to the original state.

Changing this setting also requires restarting SSMS to take effect. This is a *not-so-nice* user experience when we are in the middle of writing a query or troubleshooting a bug. So, if there are a number of unsaved query session windows already open then restarting SSMS is a costly affair. In such a case, we either have to discard all the unsaved query sessions or save them to disk so that we can resume our journey after SSMS restart .

SSMS has a much slicker option of changing this setting temporarily on *per query session basis*. I'm enlisting the steps to change the setting:

1. Right click in query editor window. Now, click **Query Options...** in the context menu (Refer screenshot)

   [image]
2. Select **Grid** under **Results** node in the left navigation pane. Now, check the **Include column headers when copying or saving the results** check box and click <kbd>OK</kbd> (Refer screenshot):

   [image]

That's it. Now the current query session will start honouring the setting change with immediate effect. We don't need to restart SSMS for this. Also, this setting change won't be propagated to any future query sessions either. Thus, this is a very quick and convenient route to follow.

Answer (score 14):

At least in SQL Server 2012, you can right click in the query window and select Query Options. From there you can select Include Headers for grid and/or text and have the Save As work the way you want it without restarting SSMS.

You'll still need to change it in Tools->Options in the menu bar to have new query windows use those settings by default.

Answer (score 7):

The same problem exists in Visual Studio, here's how to fix it there:

Go to:

```
Tools > Options > SQL Server Tools > Transact-SQL Editor > Query Results > Results To Grid
```

Now click the check box to true: "Include column headers when copying or saving the results"

Answer (score 6):

Select your results by clicking in the top left corner of the **Results** pane, right click and then select "Copy with Headers" (Refer screenshot). Paste in excel. Done!

[image]

Alternatively, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> if you like keyboard shortcuts during development.

Comment: Not so great when you need to copy a very large amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

Got here when looking for a way to make SSMS properly escape CSV separators when exporting results.

Guess what? - this is actually an option, and it is *unchecked by default*. So by default, you get broken CSV files (and may not even realize it, esp. if your export is large and your data doesn't have commas normally) - and you have to go in and click a checkbox so that your CSVs export correctly!

To me, this seems like a monumentally stupid design choice and an apt metaphor for Microsoft's approach to software in general ("broken by default, requires meaningless ritualistic actions to make trivial functionality work").

But I will gladly donate $100 to a charity of respondent's choice if someone can give me one valid real-life reason for this option to exist (i.e., an actual scenario where it was useful).

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2014 Management Studio the setting is at:

Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text > Include column headers in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue. When I used right click in the query window and select Query Options. But header rows does not show up in output CSV file.

Then I logoff the server, login again and run the script. Then it worked.

Comment: Did you try changing the `Include column headers when copying or saving the results` option? This option is visible when you select `Results` > `Grid` in left navigation pane on `Query Options` window.