# SQL Management Studio exports CSV with header from one server and without header from other server

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv

Having one instance of MSSQL Management Studio 2017 connect to two different SQL 2016 Servers. I run queries against a database on each server and save results as CSV to compare with WinMerge.

Problem: One query window saves the CSV with header row, the other query window saves the CSV without header row. I have to edit one file before comparing to get rid of the header row.

Anyone know why I get different results using one instance of Management Studio?

Comment: Did you add headers to the output during the current session?  The reason I ask; some options, when updated, only apply to new windows.

Comment: Oh I dunno perhaps thus in as simple as a SSMS setting? Have you tried googling this issue? Have you thought about creating a linked servicer so that you can leverage SQL in order to compare the results?

Comment: @destination-data You got me on the right track. I restarted Management Studio and since then I get the save as results as specified in the options. Kinda embarrassing that I didn't think of restarting. Worked fine for days.

Comment: Related post - [Saving results with headers in Sql Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10677133/465053). Also please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55218295/465053) which provides much slick way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@destination-data You got me on the right track. I restarted Management Studio and since then I get the save as results as specified in the options. Kinda embarrassing that I didn't think of restarting. Worked fine for days.

Added to mark this as answer.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at this option in SSMS:
[image: Column Header Option]

Make sure that option is checked then close the query window you are using that does not save column headers and open a new one.  Run your query in the newly opened window and see if it now saves with column headers.

Note: the same option is available for Results to Text if you are not using Results to Grid.

Comment: Yes, looked at that as well. It was unchecked, I checked it, and then unchecked it again. Did not make a difference.

Comment: And you closed and opened new query windows after changing the setting?  You shouldn't need to restart SSMS.  It changes just fine for me with new query windows and not having to restart.

Comment: No, I did not close the query windows. There is no indication that this is necessary. One has to know. Thanks for all the great tips.

Comment: There is no indication that it's necessary for any of the options, but it still is.  This is one of them.